# Correctly apply scope changes after server sent events

Tags: angularjs

My Application receive updates very often and it seems to work fine but sometimes, specially in production where the data to handle is bigger, I don't see my scopes to be correctly updates.

Here is what I'm actually doing:

```
var handleOrdersCallback = function (msg) {
  var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    var status = data.status.status;
    var order_index = _.findIndex($scope.orders, function (order) {
      return order.id === data.id;
    });

    if (order_index > -1) {
      var previousState = $scope.orders[order_index].status.status;
      $scope.orders[order_index] = data;

      if (previousState === 'unassigned' && status === 'cancelled') {
        $scope.orders.splice(order_index, 1);
        Broadcaster.remove();
      } else if (status === 'cancelled' || status === 'completed') {
        $scope.orders.splice(order_index, 1);
      } else {
        if (status === 'assigned') {
          Broadcaster.add();
        }
        Broadcaster.update(data);
      }
    } else {
      $scope.orders.unshift(data);
      if ($scope.dataLoaded) {
        Broadcaster.add();
      }
      if (status === 'unassigned') {
        Broadcaster.new(data);
      }
    }
  });
};

var source = new EventSource('/updates');
source.addEventListener('orders', handleOrdersCallback, false);
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right wrapping everything within `$scope.$apply` but to be honest I don't know if there is something to change or if it would work better coding it in a different way.

That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this block of code is how you're updating the `$scope`:

```
$scope.orders[order_index] = data;
```

The solution is to use angular.copy:

```
angular.copy(data, $scope.orders[order_index]);
```